# Why a <li> is not generated? My script does not have errors

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add automatically an `<li>` element to my media list when I upload an image using `<input type="file">` and a script. I have wrote functions and everything looks good because it does not show errors; however, my image is not displayed in my list. Can someone help to find out why?

```
<div class="explorerContainer">
<!--This is the form to upload an image-->
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
  <label for="image_uploads">Try your own image</label>
  <input type="file" id="image_uploads" name="image_uploads">
</div>
<!--Container for images list-->
<div class="medialistContainer">
  <ul class="mediaList">
    <li class="mediaItem" style="background-image: url('./src/images/testImage.jpg')"></li>
    <li class="mediaItem" style="background-image: url('./src/images/testImage2.jpg')"></li>
    <li class="mediaItem" style="background-image: url('./src/images/testImage3.jpg')"></li>
    <li class="mediaItem" style="background-image: url('./src/images/testImage4.jpg')"></li>
    <li class="mediaItem" style="background-image: url('./src/images/testImage5.jpg')"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--This script is for uploading an image-->
<script>
  var input = document.querySelector('input');
  var preview = document.querySelector('.mediaList');

  input.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  input.addEventListener('change', updateImageDisplay);

  function updateImageDisplay() {
    while(preview.firstChild) {
     preview.removeChild(preview.firstChild);
    }
    var curFiles = input.files;
    if(curFiles.length === 0) {
      var para = document.createElement('p');
      para.textContent = 'No files currently selected for upload';
      preview.appendChild(para);
    } else {
        var list = document.createElement('ol');
        preview.appendChild(list);
        for(var i = 0; i < curFiles.length; i++) {
          var listItem = document.createElement('li');
          var para = document.createElement('p');
          if(validFileType(curFiles[i])) {
            para.textContent = 'File name ' + curFiles[i].name + ', file size ' + returnFileSize(curFiles[i].size) + '.';
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(curFiles[i]);
            listItem.appendChild(image);
            listItem.appendChild(para);
          } else {
            para.textContent = 'File name ' + curFiles[i].name + ': Not a valid file type. Update your selection.';
            listItem.appendChild(para);
            }
            list.appendChild(listItem);
          }
        }
  }

var fileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png']

function validFileType(file) {
  for(var i = 0; i < fileTypes.length; i++) {
    if(file.type === fileTypes[i]) {
      return true;
      }
    }
  return false;
}

function returnFileSize(number) {
  if(number < 1024) {
    return number + 'bytes';
  } else if(number > 1024 && number < 1048576) {
      return (number/1024).toFixed(1) + 'KB';
    } else if(number > 1048576) {
       return (number/1048576).toFixed(1) + 'MB';
      }
}
</script>
```

So, the most important thing is that a user uploads an image and that image is to be displayed in a preview container and then posted into my media list container. Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: You are creating a new list element with `var list = document.createElement('ol');` but never adding it to the page, did you mean to actually make list be the reference to the existing list?

Comment: Well, I just want to add an "li" element to my existing list

Comment: then I'd try changing `var list = document.createElement('ol');` to something more like `var list = document.querySelector('ul.mediaList');`

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your approach works (at least for the first file) but remember that the `files` property of the input gets reset each time you are choosing a file.
Create another array of files to which you copy the files from the input and use this new array in your loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/syvpqgn7/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the size of the list items using css for example?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have some <li> added as examples, and they are well sized.

Comment: I've ran your code and I think the problem lies in this line... 'image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(curFiles[i]);'. Try testing your code by inputting a URL directly and it should work.

Comment: I tried, but it does not generate <li> element automatically, but thanks for helping me